# Install/Enable PDO or pdo_mysql

Tags: php, pdo

I'm developing I really need to install pdo or pdo_mysql

I'm using Ubuntu/Mint and installed everything using console commands
sudo apt-get install apache2 and so on

I've tried to install it using pecl something but without any success.
at the very last line gives an error

Comment: I've already used that method way before coming here but with no success

Comment: That's why I rarely come here. Just because it has the same reference it's not the same and as I said before I've already trued that but even using pecl ITS GIVES AN ERROR:

Comment: You could have told that **beforehand** and spared us the guessing and yourself the redundant answer. But you know, that's entirely your decision.

Comment: already said that in a comment but forgot to put in the main topic

Answer (score 1):

Installing the php5-mysql package should come with PDO extensions [(reference)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50236/make-does-not-run-with-sudo-pecl-install-pdo-why/85416#85416)

Comment: I already have that installed but don't really know how to enable it

Comment: Is this for only installing for the development server or do you need this installation done on the production server as well?

Comment: just development server

Comment: I usually install a bitnami LAMP (http://bitnami.org/) for my development side projects and you can enable PDO, which comes with it, in the php.ini file.

Comment: Now I have Apache installed
installed everything separately but I'll take that into consideration in the future